# get admin config in db2 iseries

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am working on db2 AS400 v7.1.  Could you please tell me database configuration concept in db2 as400 similar to db2 LUW?  I achieved using below command:

```
db2 UPDATE DB CFG USING CONNECT_PROC **schema.stored_Procedure**
```

usage: helps to run `stored_Procedure` each time when user logs in.

Comment: Edit your question to describe what your connect_proc would achieve on LUW,  then people can advise if that is relevant for i-series and what implementation choices exist for i-series.

Comment: Not real sure what you are trying to achieve here. There is very little configuration necessary with DB2 for i. In contrast, configuration of DB2 for LUW can be highly complex.

Comment: probably off-topic for stackoverflow...belongs on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Charles please vote for db2i to be synonym of db2400

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I created it ;)

Comment: @jmarkmurphy, can you help me config same in db2 iseries.Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not real sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to set up a program to run each time a user logs in to the 5250 green screen? What is confusing is you are asking for a database configuration. But I am not real sure what that log in is. Do you want something to run every time a user connects using ODBC or JDBC?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JDBC/ODBC for connecting to database (DB2 for i), you can use user exit QIBM_QZDA_INIT which is equivalent of connect_proc in DB2 LUW.

Link to IBM documentation for more details.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaii/rzaiimstsmpinitcl.htm

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaii/rzaiimstexdb.htm

Comment: thank you Satya. Can you please suggest the same requirement for DB2 ZOS. Is there any way to call a stored procedure automatically whenever user login in db2 ZOS similar to Connect_proc in db2 LUW.